# Python: centos get file creation time in xfs

Tags: python, centos

I have a Python script to create backup files automatically every day.

I want the script to check hard drive space and delete the oldest file automatically if space is not enough.

I named the backup file by date and convert the date to the timestamp to judge the oldest file.(the file with the smallest timestamp will be deleted)

It works currently. But I was wondering if there is another way to reach out the feature more effectively or efficiently?

The file system is XFS. I googled some research, looks like the XFS file system cannot store creation time.

Comment: XFS supports file modification time. If you create a backup and never change it (because why would you), then the last modification time is a proxy for the creation time.

Comment: @DYZ Thanks for the quick response. Yes, I have tried to use os.path.getmtime to get modification time. I'm just curious if there is any library or module that can do this feature already? Just in case the modification time has been modified.